# Facebook Graph API - Get Event that a Page have created

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get all the **Events** a **Page** have created?

I've tried the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/events
```

But I don't get any data back.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I've run in to the same issue and also updated the bug mentioned by ivan.abragimovich.

I'm not proud of it, but here is what I did as a work around.

```
$accessToken = "..."; // your OAuth token
$uid = "..."; // the id of the page you are using
$feed = $this->facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "GET", array('access_token' => $accessToken,
'limit' => 20));

// temp method of retrieving events until the page events bug is fixed.
// @see http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10399
if (array_key_exists('data', $feed) && is_array($feed['data']))
{
    foreach($feed['data'] as $item)
    {
        if ($item['type'] == "link" && strpos($item['link'], "eid=") !== false)
        {
            preg_match('/eid=(\d+)/', $item['link'], $urlMatches);
            if (count($urlMatches) == 2)
            {
                $eventId = $urlMatches[1];
                $event = $this->facebook->api("/$eventId", 'GET', array('access_token' => $accessToken));
                print_r($event);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are events that are associated with the Page? You might want to check if you can retrieve the feed. Just swap "events" with "feed" in the URL.

Comment: I created an event from the Page, so i guess it would be associated?
When i change it to "feed" i get some data

Comment: Did you check that the event is associated with the page and not your account? Change the ID to your ID and see if it's there.

Comment: It should be associated with the page, mainly because when i go to the "Events" page on the Page it shows the event. I tried to use my ID, the result was the same: nothing